# how can I animate UIImageView when user drags MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIImageView` with an image there, this image is a typical map picker. I put it on the map in storyboard and assigned some constraints.

When user drags around my map, that image stays untouched, I want to find a way of animating it - basically I want to squish it a little so it looks as it's dragged.

I already have two methods:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

}
```

and

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

}
```

But I don't know how to animate the change to UIImageView.

I tried adding to `regionWillChangeAnimated` the following code:

```
myPositionPicker.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        yawpPositionPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
```

(where `myPositionPicker` is my `UIImageView`), but I'm getting error

```
Static member animate cannot be used on instance of type UIImageView
```

I think the best animation for me would be `UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn` but I don't know how to attach it to my `UIImageView`. Can you give me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are trying to use static method "animate" on instance **myPositionPicker**. And it's wrong. Just replace

```
myPositionPicker.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
    yawpPositionPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
}, completion: nil)
```

With:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
    // Do whatever animations you want here.
}, completion: nil)
```

Next, if you want to create some simple animations (Like changing of UIImageView position or changing it's size) - you could just use your already created constraints and don't use affine transforms.

For example, if your image view is centered vertically with your map view. First, create a special @IBOutlet for this constraint in your UIViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var pickerCenterYConsraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Second, connect this outlet to constraint in storyboard.

Third, as I understood your view controller is a delegate of your map view. So, let's implement map view delegate protocol like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.pickerCenterYConsraint.constant = 25.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.pickerCenterYConsraint.constant = 0.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

And... that's all! Now your image view will be animated during map view dragging.
If you don't like this solution - you could create your own animations based on constraints. Basically you could do a lot of things with constraints. Except rotations, for example.

Comment: Is there a way of tilting the image slightly? or stretch/narrow the image? I need to achieve the effect not by moving the image up and down, but stretching it, tilting, etc.